# Implementing a smart-list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, random

I've been asked to devise a data structure called clever-list which holds items with real key numbers and offers the next operations:

**Insert(x)** - inserts a new element to the list. Should be in O(log n).

**Remove min/max** - removes and returns the min/max element in the list. Should be in O(log n) time.

**Transform** - changes the return object of remove min/max (if was min then to max, and the opposite). Should be in O(1).

**Random sample(k)** - returns randomly selected k elements from the list(k bigger than 0 and smaller than n). Should be in O(min(k log k, n + (n-k) log (n-k))).

Assumptions about the structure:
The data structure won't hold more then 3n elements at any stage. 
We cannot assume that n=O(1).
We can use Random() method which return a real number between [0,1) and preforms in O(1) time.

I managed to implement the first three methods, using a min-max fine heap. However, I don't have a clue about the random sample(k) method in this time limit. All I could find is "[Reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)", which operates in O(n) time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'transform' operation? I guess a red-black tree seems to be appropriate for your case.

Comment: Is this a homework question? I doubt in real life that anyone would ask you find a sample in "O(min(k log k, n + (n-k) log (n-k)))". If it is homework, then go talk to your TA.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all of that with a min-max heap implemented in an array, including the random sampling.

For the random sampling, pick a random number from 0 to n. That's the index of the item you want to remove. Copy that item and then replace the item at that index with the last item in the array, and reduce the count. Now, either bubble that item up or sift it down as required.

If it's on a min level and the item is smaller than its parent, then bubble it up. If it's larger than its smallest child, sift it down. If it's on a max level, you reverse the logic.

That random sampling is O(k log n). That is, you'll remove k items from a heap of n items. It's the same complexity as k calls to `delete-min`.

### Additional info

If you don't have to remove the items from the list, then you can do a naive random sampling in O(k) by selecting `k` indexes from the array. However, there is a chance of duplicates. To avoid duplicates, you can do this:

When you select an item at random, swap it with the last item in the array and reduce the count by 1. When you've selected all the items, they're in the last `k` positions of the array. This is clearly an O(k) operation. You can copy those items to be returned by the function. Then, set count back to the original value and call your `MakeHeap` function, which can build a heap from an arbitrary array in O(n). So your operation is O(k + n).

The `MakeHeap` function is pretty simple:

```
for (int i = count/2; i >= 0; --i)
{
    SiftDown(i);
}
```

Another option would be, when you do a swap, to save the swap operation on a stack. That is, save the from and to indexes. To put the items back, just run the swaps in reverse order (i.e. pop from the stack, swap the items, and continue until the stack is empty). That's O(k) for the selection, O(k) for putting it back, and O(k) extra space for the stack.

Another way to do it, of course, is to do the removals as I suggested, and once all the removals are done you re-insert the items into the heap. That's O(k log n) to remove and O(k log n) to add.

You *could*, by the way, do the random sampling in O(k) best case by using a hash table to hold the randomly selected indexes. You just generate random indexes and add them to the hash table (which won't accept duplicates) until the hash table contains `k` items. The problem with that approach is that, at least in theory, the algorithm could fail to terminate.

Comment: Maybe I confused you with my typing. The random sampling should not remove the items from the heap, only return them randomly. Does it changes the time limit that you described?

Comment: @user3680924: You have several options if you're not removing items. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the numbers in an array, and use a self-balancing binary tree to maintain a sorted index of them, then you can do all the operations with the time complexities given. In the nodes of the tree, you'll need pointers into the number array, and in the array you'll need a pointer back into the node of the tree where that number belongs.

- Insert(x) adds x to the end of the array, and then inserts it into the binary tree.
- Remove min/max follows the left/right branches of the binary tree to find the min or max, then removes it. You need to swap the last number in the array into the hole produced by the removal. This is when you need the back pointers from the array back into the tree.
- Transform toggles a bit for the remove min/max operation
- Random sample either picks k or (n-k) unique ints in the range 0...n-1 (depending whether 2k < n). The random sample is either the elements at the k locations in the number array, or it's the elements at all but the (n-k) locations in the number array.

Creating a set of k unique ints in the range 0..n can be done in O(k) time, assuming that (uninitialized) memory can be allocated in O(1) time.

First, assume that you have a way of knowing if memory is uninitialized or not. Then, you could have an uninitialized array of size n, and do the usual k-steps of a Fisher-Yates shuffle, except every time you access an element of the array (say, index i), if it's uninitialized, then you can initialize it to value i. This avoids initializing the entire array which allows the shuffle to be done in O(k) time rather than O(n) time.

Second, obviously it's not possible in general to know if memory is uninitialized or not, but there's a trick you can use (at the cost of doubling the amount of memory used) that lets you implement a sparse array in uninitialized memory. It's described in depth on Russ Cox's blog here: http://research.swtch.com/sparse

This gives you an O(k) way of randomly selecting k numbers. If k is large (ie: > n/2) you can do the selection of (n-k) numbers instead of k numbers, but you still need to return the non-selected numbers to the user, which is always going to be O(k) if you copy them out, so the faster selection gains you nothing.

A simpler approach, if you don't mind giving out access to your internal data-structure, is to do k or n-k steps of the Fisher-Yates shuffle on the underlying array (depending whether k < n/2, and being careful to update the corresponding nodes in the tree to maintain their values), and then return either a[0..k-1] or a[k..n-1]. In this case, the returned value will only be valid until the next operation on the datastructure. This method is O(min(k, n-k)).

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit on how random sample would work, especially given the complexity.

Comment: The idea is very nice, thanks. There is just one issue I'm not sure about - self balancing tree. Do you mean AVL tree? And when I'm removing min/max item, the balancing won't hurt the time limit?

Comment: @Dukeling I added details for two different methods for random sampling.